# Show all subdirectory in a folder and short the result by size

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I'm using mac and I use sudo du -h to show all sub directories in a parent directory with their size. Is there anyway i can use to sort the result by size?

I tried using `sudo du -h | sort` but the result was organize in a strange way to me (Eg. 1K - 2k - 1M - 2M - 2K...)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort using -h

```
du -h | sort -h
```

From sort man page

```
 -h, --human-numeric-sort
              compare human readable numbers (e.g., 2K 1G)
```

Comment: OS X's sort doesn't have an -h option, but you could install gsort with `brew install coreutils`.

Answer (score 2):

You should try the following code:

```
du -s * | sort -n
```

This does the following

```
du
    -s, --summarize
          display only a total for each argument

sort
    -n, --numeric-sort
          compare according to string numerical value
```

You'll get the results in kilobytes.

Answer (score 0):

here one way available for your question

du -h | sort -n

in du command -h is for human readable format

sort command  -n for numeric sort

Comment: sort -n do not sort using the K M G notation. (12k will be found after 9M), you need to sort using -h

Comment: I prefer `du -s | sort -n` instead, because it gives summary instead and K M G issue won't be there.